# D compile-time function type extraction

Tags: function, prototype, d, compile-time

D2.056

Function is a struct holding the name and the type of the function (Name and Type respectively). Binds iterates over a list of Function structs and returns a mixin string. This mixin defines for each function a new name with a '2' appended.

```
void f() { writeln("f"); }
void g() { writeln("g"); }

struct Function(string name, Prototype)
{
    const string Name = name;
    mixin("alias Prototype Type;");
}

string Binds(Functions...)()
{
    string r;
    foreach (F; Functions)
    {
        // error:
        r ~= to!string(typeid(F.Type)) ~ " " ~ F.Name ~ "2 = &" ~ F.Name ~ ";";
    }
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    mixin (Binds!(
                 Function!("f", void function()),
                 Function!("g", void function())        
                 ));

    f();
    //f2();

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling, the `to!string(typeid(F.Type))` gives an error:

```
Error: Cannot interpret & D13TypeInfo_PFZv6__initZ at compile time
   called from here: to(& D13TypeInfo_PFZv6__initZ)
   called from here: Binds()
```

Firstly, I don't see why an explicit conversion to string is required (isn't typeid already a string, if not, whats the difference between typeid and typeof?).

Secondly, I can't figure out how to get the explicit function type written out so that it can be executed in main. I can't use F.Type since it is local to the foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple problems here, but the main one is that typeid returns an object of type TypeInfo ([typeid expression](http://d-programming-language.org/expression.html#TypeidExpression)). Fortunately, you can just use F.Type.stringof. Also note that you don't need the mixin to alias Prototype as Type:

```
void f() { writeln("f"); }
void g() { writeln("g"); }

struct Function(string name, Prototype)
{
    const string Name = name;
    alias Prototype Type;
}

string Binds(Functions...)()
{
    string r;
    foreach (F; Functions)
    {
        // error:
        r ~= F.Type.stringof ~ " " ~ F.Name ~ "2 = &" ~ F.Name ~ ";";
    }
    return r;
}

import std.stdio,
    std.conv;
int main()
{
    mixin (Binds!(
                 Function!("f", void function()),
                 Function!("g", void function())        
                 ));

    f();
    f2();

    return 0;
}
```

Running this prints:

```
f
f
```

which I believe is what you're looking for.